# Query to get all levels of children for a parent in a hierarchial table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table structure is as below

| ChildId | ParentId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | null |

Output must show all levels of children for a parent

| ParentId | ChildId |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

So for every parent query has to show all the children so that if we specify any single parent in where clause, we can get all its levels of children. Would be still better if we could display level as well.

I tried using recursive CTEs but not able to achieve the required output

Comment: please avoid pasting screenshots

Comment: and show what you've already tried

Comment: i'd look into the hierarchyid column type.  this would allow you to a query like you want without a recursive CTE

Comment: *"I tried using recursive CTEs but not able to achieve the required output"* and what was that attempt? We can't answer your question of why your code isn't working if you don't include said code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a strange requirement.  In addition to traversing the hierarchy, you also want all nodes to be paired with themselves.  This is not part of the original data, but can be added separately:

```
with cte as (
      select parentId, childid
      from t
      where parentid is not null
      union all
      select cte.parentId, t.childid
      from cte join
           t
           on t.parentId = cte.childId
     )
select *
from cte
union all
select childid, childid
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=af3e9a7dbb43bd730a33ebb0c51310e3) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to add extra entries beyond the hierarchy, but you can do the levels bit like this..

```
declare @T table (
    id        integer identity(1,1) primary key,
    ChildId   Integer,
    ParentId  Integer
)

insert @T (ChildId, Parentid)
      select 4,null
union select 3,4
union select 2,3
union select 1,3

;WITH CTE (ParentId, ChildId, Lvl) AS (
    SELECT ParentId, ChildId, 1
      FROM @T 
     WHERE ParentId IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT T.ParentId, T.ChildId, Lvl + 1
      FROM @T T JOIN CTE E ON E.ChildId = T.ParentId
)
SELECT ChildId,ParentId,Lvl
  FROM CTE
 ORDER BY Lvl
```